# 405 Method Not Allowed ReactJS Post to Django

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-urls, axios, react-router-v4

I have a Class-based view that inherits APIView from Django Rest Framework but when I make a request from react to the django view, react raises a 405 Method Not Allowed.

**Django View**

```
class TakeSectionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'data': "hello world"})
```

**React API with Axios**

```
function fetchExamQuestion(classId, sectionId) {
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
  const url = `http://localhost:8100/exams/section/data/`;
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: {
      section_id: sectionId,
      class_id: classId
    },
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken}
  }).then(result => result.data);
}
```

Here is the ReactJS code making initiating the request:

**React Code**

```
function* fetchQuestion({ sessionId }) {
  try {
    const classId = yield select(getCurrentClassId);
    const result = yield Api.fetchExamQuestion(classId, sessionId);
    if (result.successful) {
      yield put({ type: EXAM.FETCH_QUESTION_SUCCESSFUL, practiceDetail: result.data });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: EXAM.FETCH_QUESTION_FAILURE, error });
  }
}
```

Here is the error I see in the console:
[image]

Another detail that might help. It looks like it only allows GET requests. How can I change that?

[image]

Comment: Can you send csrftoken with post data. If you don't using token based authentication you don't need header. If you are using token based auth, you don't need csrftoken.

Comment: I am not using token based Auth. I have other Post requests that work.

Comment: Can you pl post the contents of your exams app's urls.py ?